# getting fixture from parameterized for multiple tests

Tags: python, pytest, flask-restful

my code

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ("username", "password", "message"),
    (
        ("", "", b"Username is required."),
        ("a", "", b"Password is required."),
        ("test", "test", b"already registered"),
    ),
)
def test_register_validate_input(client, username, password, message):
    response = client.post(
        "/register", data={"username": username, "password": password}
    )
    assert message in response.data

def test_register_delete_input(client, username, password, message):
    response = client.delete(
        "/register", data={"username": username, "password": password}
    )
    assert message in response.data
```

if i run python -m pytest i am getting

```
fixture 'username' not found
```

however if i remove the block for

```
def test_register_delete_input(client, username, password, message):
    response = client.delete(
        "/register", data={"username": username, "password": password}
    )
    assert message in response.data
```

the test works

1. How can i use the fixture in the delete test as well?
2. the difference is only with post/delete in the two tests. Is there a way to combine?

Comment: Create an actual fixture and parametrize it, then use this fixture in both tests rather than directly parametrizing the test arguments.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could copypaste the `@pytest.mark.parametrize(...)` block from the first test to the second test, because it only parametrizes the first test but not the second.
   Alternatively, do what this user recommended here - [getting fixture from parameterized for multiple tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74717502/getting-fixture-from-parameterized-for-multiple-tests#comment131884076_74717502)
2. It could be combined, in theory; but, since you're testing two different actions (`post` in first one and `delete` in the second one), I'd say it's better to keep these two tests separate.